# Access power bi groups and report using service principal and postman

Tags: java, powerbi, postman

1. I want use service principal which is the use of client_id and client_secret to get token and then pass this token to another api that get groups but i am getting 403.
2. I have created service principal group with name POWERBI_API_036 which contains my application with the name SystemServer
3. Now i have a server side application (SystemServer) This is also because i dont want to use username and password to get token because i want to create a way many customers to be able to authenticate without giving there password.
4. This is what i have now i succesfully generate a token but i am not able to use it to get groups or reports. -- client-id and secret have been changed for privacy
   [image]

Added the token in header but i get 403. I am lost at this point on how service principal helps authenticate without password or what am i doing wrong ? Please

[image]

Comment: try to follow this will help https://www.loginworks.com/blogs/how-to-embed-power-bi-reports-into-your-application-using-power-bi-rest-apis/
OR 
https://www.loginworks.com/blogs/how-to-embed-power-bi-reports-into-your-application-using-power-bi-rest-apis/
OR
http://dataap.org/blog/2019/03/30/power-bi-embedded-service-principal-postman/

Comment: @AnkUser this links are username and password based token generation. I need an app only token ( Do you know about service principal ) ?

Comment: True I myself tried with client Id and secret as mentioned in your question, I was not able to generate Access token. But using username and password I was able to have Access token, fetch reports and so on

Comment: For me i able to generate token but when i put it in the header and try to get groups i get 403 status @AnkUser

Comment: Service principal and how to use is not well documented https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embed-service-principal

Comment: if you managed to solve it just update the answer